# Can I get Auron's Masamune without beating the Dark Aeon?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

Apparently, the path to the statue of Lord Mi'ihen is being guarded by some pretty nasty summoners.

I tried warping to Djose Highroad, but it puts me on the beach where the Crusaders battled Sin. I can't seem to find a way to the north side of Mushroom Rock, and the south side has some Aeons I'm not prepared to fight.

**Is there any way to get to the statue without dealing with the Dark Aeons?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you *can* get to the Mii'hen Highroad from the north side.  Move left from where you start, and you'll eventually be able to climb the wreckage of the machina.

If you can't find it, you can still go from the south side; the aeons chasing you event is random.  If you get the cutscene, run screaming back south to leave the area, and try again.  What I did is give those people a wide berth, and that seemed to do it.  Not sure if that helps you avoid the cutscene, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the cutscene should only occur if you are too close to the first two summoners.  If you hug the left wall you shouldn't initiate the cutscene.

Answer (score 0):

Yea its because the Mi'ihen Highroad actually continues right through the first area of mushroom rock taking you to the beach area "Mushroom Rock - Aftermath" then continues along Djose Highroad.

But the game makes you climb the long route through mushroom rock the first time around and once the guy infront of the Machina Wreckage moves out of your way on the beach (after Djose events) the game doesnt actually tell you its possible to go back even though theres all new NPCs and such spawned there now that talk about the aftermath of operation Mi'ihen.

So yea just goto the bottom of Djose highroad (airship location : Mushromrock - aftermath) then walk south-west, climb the creates on the beach and it takes you directly to the first area of mushroom rock above the spot where the crusaders initially redirect you through the valley to the command center (which can never be reentered because the machina lift is now broken after sin attacked) and once the crusaders leave, the roads open for a while, then after the highbridge scene the dark magnus sisters will be blocking roughly the same spot where the crusader blocked you. fortunately if you enter from the north side like i explained above you can just go south, turn left to get the lord miihen statue for auron, then go south more and hug the wall tight to the left and goto vally again to collect the jhect sphere there too making the dark sisters totally optional